# Create array with for and sum total

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I stuck here

i wanna sum total from checked checkbox value, and i use array

```
$check=$_POST[check];
$hit=count($check);
for($h=0;$h<=$hit-1;$h++) {
echo $check[$h];
//output without array : 1,2,3
//i wanna create array ex : $array = array('1', '2', '3');
//and sum total with echo array_sum($array);
//and total is 6
}
```

how to generate or create array from my loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the sum like this -

```
$sum = '';
for($h=0;$h<$hit;$h++) {
    $sum += $check[$h];
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Awesome, work smooth!! Thank you so much :) Correct Answered for you

Comment: your welcome, you need to approve the answer then :)

Answer (score 3):

You say you want to create an array like `$array = array('1', '2', '3');`, but according to your code you already have that array, ie `$check == array('1', '2', '3');` I'm not too clear on what your question is, but assuming that

`$check` is equal to `$_POST[check]` is equal to `array('1', '2', '3');`

then here is no need for `count()` or loops or creating another array. You just need one line:

```
$sum = array_sum($check); // 6
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/xhd3FuRP)